# What comes after learning object oriented programming in C++?

Tags: self-learning, programming, secondary-education

> What comes after learning basic and object oriented programming in C++ , I also cover file handling .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many bits in the Standard Template Library that you should know about

1. random, chrono
2. have you learned all your containers? `unordered_map`?
3. I really like `std::optional` and `variant`
4. Do you know what structured bindings are?
5. Smart pointers are very important.
6. Move semantics.
7. Oh, templates and template meta programming.
8. Lambdas.

That should keep you busy for the next year or two.

Comment: can i learn DSA ? for logic building and memory management ? after learning these 8 concepts ?

Comment: What is DSA? If that's a specific application, then of course you're free to learn it.

Comment: Data structure and algorithm !!

Comment: @Hamza you can not study "dsa" independent of the language. For instance, pointers are the best illustration of trees. If you learn about complexity and you want to measure runtimes you need `chrono`. Other example: In engineering applications, the most common data structure is an array. But the algorithms take a whole math/physics class.  So again, you can not study DSA by itself.

Comment: means first i now the concepts of `pointer` , `chrono` etc then i start learning DSA ?